# jQuery won't append a clone declared at document ready

Tags: javascript, jquery, append, clone

My issue is that if I create a clone variable on page load, jQuery will only append it once. Weird!

```html
<p>Click to copy</p>
<div id="container">
    <div class="element">This is an element!</div>
</div>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    var obj = $(".element").clone(true);
    $("p").click(function () {
        //alert(obj); //Just to see if the variable is still an object.
        $("#container").append(obj);
    });
});
```

Here is my CodePen link http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Fwduf

This is what I'm getting after 5 clicks:

> Click to copy
>
> This is an element!
>   This is an element!

What I should be seeing:

> Click to copy
>
> This is an element!
>   This is an element!
>   This is an element!
>   This is an element!
>   This is an element!
>   This is an element!

Interestingly, if I move the variable deceleration inside the click event, the append works completely as expected.

Comment: so You know the problem. still you need help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to clone it every time

**[Codepen Demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ptFKc)**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var obj = $(".element");
    $("p").click(function () {
        //alert(obj); //Just to see if the variable is still an object.
        $("#container").append(obj.clone(true));
    });
});
```

In your case you are creating a new cloned element only once, after that you are just moving the existing element from one place to another

Comment: Thank you for your fast response. However, I don't feel that I worded my question correctly and provided the right example of my overall intention. [Click here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22174241/) to go to my updated question.

Answer (score 1):

Arun's answer is correct but does not explain *why* you need to clone your template element each time you want a new element.

One feature of an individual DOM element, that you may not have been aware of, is that *it can only have one parent*. This makes sense as the DOM tree connects elements up, down, and sideways to each other and only have a single parent-element link (and a single next and single prev sibling element link) but a list of multiple children.

When you clone an element, you create a new DOM element that is effectively a new branch in a DOM tree (if only a small one). Calling append adds the element to its new parent, but it also points a parent link of your clone to its new parent. By appending the same element over and over you are simply changing the parent of a single element (i.e. moving it in the DOM tree).

As the interaction only runs at *user interface speed* (i.e. mouse click), you might as well simplify your code to:

```
$("p").click(function () {
    $("#container").append($(".element:first").clone(true));
});
```

### JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/7h8MK/1/