# jQuery wont append a clone on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, append, clone

If you click option 2, it appends the original clone from page load but it wont repeat every time the button is clicked.

```html
<a href="#" class="modify">1. Turn the element red...</a><br />
<a href="#" class="copy">2. Append the original black element...</a><br /><br />
<div id="container">
    <div class="element">This is an element!</div>
</div>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    var obj = $(".element").clone(true);
    $(".copy").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        //alert(obj); //Just to see if it still exists.
        $("#container").append(obj);
    });
    $(".modify").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(".element").css("color", "#F00");
    });
});
```

Here is my CodePen link http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dsvLm

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One feature of an individual DOM element, that you may not have been aware of, is that *it can only have one parent*. This makes sense as the DOM tree connects elements up, down, and sideways to each other and only have a single parent-element link (and a single next and single prev sibling element link) but a list of multiple children.

When you clone an element, you create a new DOM element that is effectively a new branch in a DOM tree (if only a small one). Calling append adds the element to its new parent, but it also points a parent link of your clone to its new parent. By appending the same element over and over you are simply changing the parent of a single element (i.e. moving it in the DOM tree).

Instead just make a new clone of your disconnected cloned object (in its original state) each time you need one:

### JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/7h8MK/2/

```
$("#container").append(obj.clone(true));
```

Comment: Ah! That's exactly what I'm looking for. Thank you. I didn't think to clone the clone.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create the clone while appending.Use:

```
var obj = $(".element");
$(".copy").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    //alert(obj); //Just to see if it still exists.
    $("#container").append(obj.clone(true));
});
```

**[Demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bzscp)**

Comment: I want the original element back not the cloned red one. It seems to work correctly once, but fails after that.

Comment: @Milind Anantwar: The reason this does not work is because you removed the initial `clone()` of the element, which would have saved the initial state of the object. Instead it references the live first element (including any colour change).